# How to remove leading 0 in a version in powershell?

Tags: powershell

Basically how do I remove the leading 0s in something like

1.0002.3.20 -> 1.2.3.20

with powershell?

Comment: Please provide more context. Where is the version number coming from? Why does it have leading zeroes? Why do you need to remove them?

Comment: The simplest way is probably to say `([Version] "1.0002.3.20").ToString()` - this will output `1.2.3.20`.

Comment: Thanks Bill! I knew there was some trick I hadn't figured out yet. Also kind of weird I need a backstory to my question Daniel, that doesn't really change the question or would provide any more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ver is the version number

```
$verArray=$ver.split(".")
$tempVer=($verArray | ForEach({ $_ -replace '^0+(?=[^.])' }) )
$newVer=[string]::join($tempVer,".")
Remove-Variable verArray, tempVer
$newVer
```

This should, in a long-hand form, provide you with the version sans leading zeroes.